# How do I know how many memory that Arduino is use after my code is running for a few time

Tags: arduino-mega, memory-usage

When I upload my program to Arduino it says the memory that the program is used. But what if I use a bad management of dynamic memory, or any object is created several times in use a lot of memory and the Arduino memory overload.

How do I know the current size of memory that Arduino is use?

I am thinking about to create a function in Arduino that return me this information if I send it a request command, but also I don't know how do I inspect the Arduino memory.

Note: I am using the Board: Arduino Mega 2560.

I read the question and the answer for [Measure SRAN usage](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11845/measure-sram-usage)

In the question @fuenfundachtzig ask:

***Can I determine how much SRAM I have left in the live system?***

In my question I am asking about how do I know or monitoring my program memmory. Ok the Measure SRAN usage answer give me the tips or tools to develop my idea, but the question is not the same.

I am tryin to know in an specific time what is the size of my memmory.

#### example...

```
void setup() { //doing some configuration };

void loop() {  // invoke some functions and evil function  };

// in other place a evil function 

void evil(){
MyClass * instance = new MyClass();
//play with the instance and it class create other instances....
//and a dynamic memmory is used but not deleted.
}
```

I am trying to know if it happens and how do I detect with Arduino? I am not talking about how much memmory do I left in the live system.

Comment: memory used = total memory − free memory.

Comment: You should not just _say_ your question is different, you should _explain_ how it is different. Be _specific_ about what you are asking for. At this point, it still looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it looks like you want to figure out if you have a memory leak. Since the objects get allocated continuously you will end up having less and less free memory.

You can use the functions presented in the sister question answered very nicely by Edgar (more specifically the complex one that calculates all the memory going through the allocation chain).

You can check the returned value every so often (few seconds/minutes depending on your needs) and if the free memory value drops continuously then you have a memory leak somewhere. This will not tell you where the leak is of course. Also this should work well while debugging the code, but would probably not be a good idea to leave it in "production" code.

Comment: I will try with the function that Edgar post, thank you for the answer and comments.