# Intializing Serial crashes UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have a somewhat large sketch that uses the `Adafruit_ssd1306`(I2C) library for a 128X64 LCD. The sketch is a designed to be an alarm clock. When I upload the sketch with out initializing serial, it works as designed. However if I do intialize serial:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

the program fails to run on my UNO. After many hours of troubleshooting I noticed I have several large char arrays that may be the culprit.

```
const char *menusDisplay[] = {"1. Alarm-is Off", "2. Month", "3. Hour", "4. Minute", "5. Exit", "6. Alarm Set", NULL};
const char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep" , "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", NULL};
const int days[] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

The months array as 12 elements. If I shorted it down to 2 elements and upload the programs with serial initialized, the program runs. At first I thought is was a memory leak in perhaps the `Adafruit_ssd1306`. But I also have another LCD library `Adafruit_ssd1306syp` that the issue occurred too. So that ruled out those libraries.

When I compile the sketch without Serial:

```
Sketch uses 16,846 bytes (52%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 737 bytes (35%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,311 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
```

With Serial:

```
Sketch uses 17,862 bytes (55%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 910 bytes (44%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,138 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
```

Any ideas of what may be going on? I would load the sketch but its very large. If needed, I can try to cut it down and reproduce the issue.

Comment: The reported percentage of “dynamic memory” used is actually the percentage of RAM used by static and global variables. A significant amount of RAM can be used by the heap and the stack, which is not reported here as it can only be measured at run time. C.f. [this answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/11848) and [this answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/777) on how to measure the amount of free RAM.

Comment: @EdgarBonet That was it. I ran out ram. Make this answer so you can get the credit. I have 2k of ram (Arduino) to start with. With serial initialized & my code, I have around 100 at the start of the program. I am sure that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EdgarBonet pointed out in a comment, I need to check my dynamic ram, which could be used by the Heap and Stack. The class can be found [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory) to measure ram usage. Since links can die, here is the code:

Here is the header:

```
/* MemoryFree.h */

// MemoryFree library based on code posted here:
// http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1213583720/15
// Extended by Matthew Murdoch to include walking of the free list.

#ifndef MEMORY_FREE_H
#define MEMORY_FREE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int freeMemory();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Here is the .cpp

```
/* MemoryFree.cpp */

#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif

extern unsigned int __heap_start;
extern void *__brkval;

/*
 * The free list structure as maintained by the 
 * avr-libc memory allocation routines.
 */
struct __freelist {
  size_t sz;
  struct __freelist *nx;
};

/* The head of the free list structure */
extern struct __freelist *__flp;

#include "MemoryFree.h"

/* Calculates the size of the free list */
int freeListSize() {
  struct __freelist* current;
  int total = 0;
  for (current = __flp; current; current = current->nx) {
    total += 2; /* Add two bytes for the memory block's header  */
    total += (int) current->sz;
  }
  return total;
}

int freeMemory() {
  int free_memory;
  if ((int)__brkval == 0) {
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)&__heap_start);
  } else {
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)__brkval);
    free_memory += freeListSize();
  }
  return free_memory;
}
```

From this I was able to see how much ram was used. Of the avialable 2k, I had only 100k left. So now I know why my program is crashing, I need a solution. The solution was to store the static content in program memory (PROGMEM):

```
const char* const months[] PROGMEM = 
    {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

const uint8_t days_of_month[] PROGMEM = 
    {
        31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no other code is posted, I am going to guess that you're performing a loop on months[], which has 13 elements (last one is NULL).

You are likely also trying to walk the days[] array (or some other array), which only has 12 elements.

Since days[] or the other (not pasted) array doesn't have 13 elements, you're probably overriding a critical bootloader memory which causes a crash.